# Drag and drop function does not work on some UI in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver's dragAndDrop() function on some sample UI.

Sample 1) http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

```
    driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");
    WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.id("column-a"));
    WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform();
```

Sample 2) http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default

```
    driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default");
    WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
    WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
    WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform();
```

I am using exactly the same APIs. However, sample 2 works well, sample 1 just DO NOT WORK. In sample 1 the mouse seems to click and hold on empty space instead of on the "From" element, and no further movement at all.

I've tried other actions suggested on google search such as:

```
keydown().click().click().keyup() and

clickandhold().movetoelement().release()
```

on sample 1. But neither of them works.

What could be the problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code is helpful for you

public class darganddropTest
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");

System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size());

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));

driver.findElement(By.id("draggable")).click();

Actions a = new Actions(driver);

WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));

WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));

a.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

}

}

Comment: Try to format your code, so that it is readable.