# Selenium / Java: "Actions" always releasing element on my cursor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have exactly the same problem as [Selenium / Java: "Actions" always releasing element on my cursor even with correct parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174973/selenium-java-actions-always-releasing-element-on-my-cursor-even-with-correct-parameters).

There're no answers to the original post, which surprise me a lot, since drag and drop is quite a common operation in selenium.

The drag and drop test page I use is https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop.

The selenium java code I use is below:

```
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");

    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("column-a"));
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.clickAndHold(from)
            .moveToElement(to)
            .release(to).build().perform();
```

The behaviour is exactly same as described in the original post. Instead of dropping the 'from' object into the 'to' position, it always drop it to where my mouse is when the browser open the page.

Say I put my mouse cursor initially at the right most side of my desktop window, when selenium test start and browser opens the url, the test drop the 'from' object to the same location of my mouse, instead to the 'to' location. I tried running the test multiple times, same behaviour always.

Since the code I use is the standard way of doing drag and drop, and the same code is used in so many tutorial. What could be the root cause?

Comment: Found another evidence of this issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073837/drag-and-drop-function-does-not-work-on-some-ui-in-selenium-webdriver?rq=2. Any expert can explain why it's not working?